# Find all triplets in an array that sum to a given value.There are duplicates in the array

Tags: c++

This is the code I wrote-

```
void FindTriplet(int arr[], int size, int x) {
    sort(arr,arr+size);
    for(int i=0;i<size-2;i++)
    {
        int l=i+1;
        int r=size-1;
        while(l<r)
        {
            int sum=arr[i]+arr[l]+arr[r];
            if(sum==x)
            {
                cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[l] << " " << arr[r] << endl;
                l++;
                r--;
            }
            else if(sum<x)
            {
                l++;
            }
            else 
            {
                r--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity of O(n^3) is not acceptable.
But this code is failing on cases like-
1 1 1 1 where required sum is 3.
Ans. 1 1 1  repeated 4 times

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: The thing is my program is not deviating from anything. It is giving the correct solution on array without duplicates. I just don't know what changes to make to make it work for duplicates

Comment: @jamesgem Not sure your approach can be made to work. Presence of duplicates means that you cannot discard either the left or the right bound without further analysis, Is there any reason not to use the simple brute force approach?

Comment: @john It has O(N^3) complexity. That's why

Comment: @jamesgem Sure, you should make any constraints on solving this problem clear in the question

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux edited

Comment: @jamesgem -- Did you get this question from one of the "online judge" sites?  If so, please note that these sites are notorious for giving questions that have naïve solutions that work for simple cases, but do not work with the massive amounts of data they may give it or with the special requirements.  The goal is for you to come up with the non-naïve solution, and that may require doing things much differently than the naïve approach.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am a beginner in programming and that's why i asked this doubt because i was not able to formulate a solution further than this

Comment: @jamesgem Well your issue has very little to do with programming.  It comes down to formulating a solution with pencil and paper first, and then writing the code.  Second, note that many of these questions may involve getting into having knowledge of data structures and algorithms to reduce the complexity, even if on the surface the questions sound "simple" (maybe not this question, but it may).  If you never dealt with data structures, then you will have further issues.

Comment: After sorting, `std::unique()` can be used to remove duplicates (by moving them to the end).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... you do not want duplicates right? then why don't you stop the loop when you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do handle duplicates when you found correct sum:

```
if (sum==x)
{
    // skip and count duplicates
    const auto oldL = l;
    do {
        ++l;
    } while (l <= r && arr[oldL] == arr[l]);
    const auto oldR = r;
    do {
        --r;
    } while (l <= r && arr[oldR] == arr[r]);

    // resulting count
    const auto count = (arr[oldL] == arr[oldR]
                       ? (l - oldL) * (l - oldL - 1) / 2
                       : ((l - oldL) * (oldR - r)));

    for (int j = 0; j != count; ++j) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " " << arr[oldL] << " " << arr[oldR] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/P7SbcZ)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better make use of STL classes. I wrote some code for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void findTripletSums(const std::vector<int>& arr, int tripleSum)
{
    std::map<int,int> arrMap; // counts the number of times the number is repeated
    for(auto a : arr)
    {
        arrMap[a]++;
    }

    for(auto itrI = arrMap.begin(); itrI != arrMap.end(); ++itrI)
    {
        int arrI = itrI->first;
        if(arrI*3 == tripleSum && itrI->second >= 3)
        {
            cout << arrI << " " << arrI << " " << arrI << "; ";
            return;
        }
        auto itrJ   = itrI;
        for(++itrJ; itrJ != arrMap.end(); ++itrJ)
        {
            int arrJ        = itrJ->first;
            int complement  = tripleSum-arrI-arrJ;

            if(complement < itrJ->first)
            {
                break;
            }

            if(complement == arrJ)
            {
                if(itrJ->second >= 2)
                {
                     cout << arrI << " " << arrJ << " " << arrJ << "; ";
                }
                break;
            }

            if(arrMap.find(complement) != arrMap.end())
            {
                cout << arrI << " "  << arrJ << " " << complement << "; ";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    findTripletSums({0,1,3,3,2,4,6}, 7);
    cout << "\n";
    findTripletSums({1,2,3,4,5,6}, 7);
    cout << "\n";
    findTripletSums({0,1,1,1,1,2}, 3);


    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
0 1 6; 0 3 4; 1 2 4; 1 3 3;                                                                                                                                                        
1 2 4;                                                                                                                                                                             
0 1 2; 1 1 1;
```